# Does Christianity have any explicit position on Jewish matrilineality?

Tags: baptism, judaism, infants, inter-faith

Among denominations which recognize infant baptism, in my experience, Christians — even those who are otherwise not really practicing — baptize their children as a matter of course. In cases where the father belongs to one denomination and the mother to another (i.e. Eastern Orthodox and Roman Catholic), the children are baptized in a church belonging to (and later follow) the denomination of the father. This might all be a secular custom more so than a religious prescription, but it seemed pretty clear that the religion is inherited patrilineally.

For Jews religion is inherited matrilineally, which is an actual and important religious prescription.

In a case where the father is Christian and the mother is Jewish, would the father in any way transgress against his faith if he did not have his children baptized? Or is this issue pre-empted by a prescription to only marry within the faith, in which case there is no religious position on the matter since the religious position would have been to not end up in this situation in the first place?

Comment: Catholicism has very clear rules on this.

Comment: Some factual support is needed for this question. At the moment it is purely anecdotal based on 'my experience'. Some substantiation is required as to '.... for Jews religion is inherited matrilineally ... ' and 'among denominations ... as a matter of course...' I don't see any trends which would support this question, myself. It appears to be purely a matter of opinion as a platform for a debate.

Comment: I don't know that statement is true for Catholics.  Pretty sure if you're married in the Catholic Church you make a promise when you're married to baptize and raise children in the Catholic faith regardless of the denomination of the mother or the father.

Comment: @KenGraham what are those rules? I think that would be a pretty good answer to this question.

Comment: @PeterTurner Indeed.  I was told that if I wanted a Catholic priest to officiate my wedding to a Protestant woman I had to promise to do all in my power to raise my children Catholic.